# Leaflet JS: do event objects need to be instantiated before defining event handler

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I am trying to create event handlers based on the success of the location() method on the leaflet js map class

Here is what I have at the moment:

```
function initMap() {
    var map = L.map('map').locate({setView: false});

    map.on('locationfound', function(s) {
        map.setView(s.latlng).setZoom(14);
    });

    map.on('locationerror', function(e) {
        message: 'Sorry, We were unable to determine your current location.';
    });

    L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.cloudmade.com/0e35616818144f159fa412e57f190939/997/256/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, Imagery © <a href="http://cloudmade.com">CloudMade</a>',
        maxZoom: 18
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

Does 's' or 'e' need to be initiated prior to defining the event handler, or does s and e assume the role as LocationEvent object through the event handler.  If it does, what is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't need to be initiated. The function you pass as event listener gets called with certain objects as arguments (in this case it's location data) automatically.